# Redirecting to another page in online getting 404 not found error in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hi While redirecting to another page getting 404 not found error in online.Home page is displaying correctly.But while clicking on any other links getting as 404 not found error.Thanks In Advance.In Local System it is working perfectly but after deploying in online server geting 404 not found error.

Not Found

The requested URL /welcome/career was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

.htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Header file: Navigation Code

```
<ul class="menu">
            <li><a href="<?php echo base_url('welcome/career');?>">Careers</a></li>
            <li><a href="<?php echo base_url('testimonial');?>">Testimonial</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change Your Code to :

```
<ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="<?php echo site_url('welcome/career');?>">Careers</a></li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo site_url('testimonial');?>">Testimonial</a></li>
```

if work for you , because index.php not removed from url.
check rewrite_module apache is on.

Comment: But What is the difference between site url and base url because in base url i have given http://www.domain.com/ then what is the problem with that

Comment: when you use site_url() , index.php added to your url, but you clear value base_url() in config.php and do not remove index.php from your url , this problem happend.

Answer (score 0):

Do some tweaking in config.php:

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = "REQUEST_URI";
```

One more thing if you use Linux Server so make these changes is compulsory.

1) Your class name should start with Capital Letter i.e `cat` should be `Cat`.

2) Save the controller class with Capital Letter i.e `cat.php` should be `Cat.php`.